# Which tool is used to create firewall rules on Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, iptables, firewalld

What is a recommended way to set up firewall rules on Fedora 20/Centos 7/RHEL 7 currently? I know about relatively new replacement of itpables service by firewalld service. Which command-line user utility should I use to work with firewalld? I googled three options but I don't know any of these so the question is which one to learn:

1. firewall-cmd
2. iptables command
3. nftables

Comment: At the end of the day they are all the same. Just learn the one you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: In F20 you should be using firwall-cmd. If you know what you're doing then you can use #2 or #3.